# PC cannot detect USB when update firmware for alwinner board

Tags: android, firmware

I have a board alwinner running Android/linux. When I update the firmware for the board, the indicator light on the board turns red. After that the PC cannot detect the USB connection through USB otg. The red light remains on consistently. Is there any way to fix this issue ?
Now, I cannot do anything. when plug in the adapter, it will turn to red light after some seconds.